# Show that there is a unique extension $\overline{T}\in(l^2)'$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider the subspace $Y=\{\{x_k\}_k\in l^2:x_k=0\ $ whenever $k$ is odd $\}\subset l^2$ and a linear functional $T\in Y', T\ne 0.$ Show to there is a unique linear extension $\overline{T}\in(l^2)'$ of $T$ with $||\overline{T}||_{(l^2)'}=||T||_{Y'}.$

I know what to do if I have a defined functional $T:W\to \mathbb{R}, \{x_k\}_k\mapsto 2017x_k$, with $W=\{\{x_k\}_k\in l^1, x_k=0, \forall k\in\mathbb{N}, k\ne 2017\}$. In this case I would calculate the dual norm of $T$ and then I would find $\overline{T}$ extension of $T$ with $\overline{T}(\{x_k\})=\sum_1^\infty x_ky_k$ with $\{y_k\}\in l^{\infty}$.

How I can solve this problem without knowing the definition of the functional $T$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The existence of a extension is guaranteed by the Hahn-Banach-Theorem, but in general this extension is not unique (depending on the Banach space). Here, you have a Hilbert space and in this case you don't need the Hahn-Banach-Theorem and we also get uniqueness of the extension.

Note that $Y$ is closed subspace and thus also a Hilbert-Space. The Riesz representation theorem implies that $T(x) = \langle x,y \rangle$ for a unique $y \in Y$ and $\|T\|=\|y\|$. This gives the unique extension $\overline{T}(x) = \langle x, y \rangle$.

Let us prove that the extension is unique: Any other extension $L \colon H \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has a representation $L(x) = \langle x, l \rangle$ with $l \in H$ and $\|l\|=\|y\|$. Decompose $$l = y' + u$$ with $y' \in Y$ and $u \in Y^\perp$. Note that we used the geometry of Hilbert spaces in form of the existence of an orthogonal projection. Then we have for $x \in Y$ that $$\langle x, y \rangle = \overline{T}(x) = T(x) = L(x) = \langle x, y' \rangle.$$
Thus $\langle x, y-y' \rangle =0$. Taking $x=y-y'$ we get that $y=y'$. Now we have
$$\|y\|^2 = \|l\|^2 = \|y'\|^2 + \|u\|^2 = \|y\|^2 +\|u\|^2$$
and thus $u=0$. This proves $l=y$.

Comment: $W$ is a Hilbert-Space too? So in general by Riesz representation theorem there always exists an extension $\overline{T}$ caused by the subspace is a Hilbert-Space?

Comment: In the first case, $Y$ is closed and the metric is induced by an inner product. Thus $Y$ is a Hilbert space. In general, the extension is not unique and this question depends on the geometry of the corresponding Banach space $X$. (E.g. if $X'$ is strict convex, then every extension is unique.) In the case of $l^1$ the extension is not unique. If $T(x) = 2017 x_{2017}$ on $W$, then you can take any $(y_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \in l^\infty$ with $y_{2017} = 2017$ and $|y_i| \leq 2017$ for $i \neq k$.

Comment: Ok, but $\overline{T}(x)=\langle x,y\rangle$ it's the inner product extension on $l^2$, but how the norms can be the same? I have difficulty to understand how the extension works. You said there is a unique extension for a unique $y\in Y$, but I can see more than a unique element in $Y$.

Comment: We have simply $\|\overline{T}\| = \|y\| = \|T\|$ again by the Riesz representation theorem. If $L$ is another extension, i.e. the restriction to $Y$ is $T$ and $\|L\| = \|T\|$, then there exists an $l \in l^2$ with $L(x) = \langle x,l \rangle$ and $\|l\| = \|T\|$. Now, we have $0=\overline{T}(u)-L(u) = \langle y-l,u \rangle$ for any $u \in Y$, i.e. $y-l \in Y^{\perp}$. That implies $\|\overline{T}\|=\|L|=\|l\| =\|(l-y)+y\|= \|y\|+\|l-y\| = \|\overline{T}\| + \|\overline{T}-L\|$. Thus $\|\overline{T}-L\|=0$.

Comment: I don't need the definition of the inner product on $Y$ to say that it is a Hilbert space, right? I need only to know that there is a certain inner product.

Comment: Yes, of course! We didn't use any special property of $l^2$, i.e. we can just replace $^l2$ by a Hilbert space, say $H$, and $Y$ is now just a closed subspace.

Comment: @p4sch When working with subspaces of $\ell^p$ spaces, is any linear extension defined as the sum of the product of two sequences, one in $\ell^p$ and one in the dual of $\ell^p$?

Comment: My argument is based on the fac that any subspace of a Hilbert space is a Hilbert space. I have added to my intial answer additionally the argument why the extension is unique. I don't understand your question: We can identity $l^p$ with $l^q$, where $1/p+1/q=1$ if $p < \infty$. So any linear functional $L$ on $l^p$ is given as $L(x) = \langle x,y \rangle = \sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k y_k$ with $y \in l^q$. Moreover, for example in $l^1$, is not necessarily unique. There is an unique norm-preserving extension if and only if $X'$ is strictly convex. (Theorem by Taylor-Foguel)

Comment: What you meant to say in your last comment is that we can identify the DUAL of $l^p$ with $l^q$.